# PHP - Database Array to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm currently searching a MySQL database for results based on an input value.
Once the data has been pulled, it is included into an array and than encoded to JSON.

At the moment the code works as expected, however it does not loop through every database result, it just pulls the first results that contains the input data, even if there are multiple results that match.

For example. if i input the letter "e" into the front end search form, this should get all results that contain the letter "e", however it only gets the first result with the letter "e" rather than looping through the enter table (there are 3 other results that should be pulled).

Is there any way to modify my current code to loop correctly and get all results that match the query?

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $search_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    $query = 'SELECT kbarticleid,subject FROM swkbarticles WHERE subject LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';
    $initial = $search_db->query($query);

    while($results = $initial->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array['kbarticleid'] = $results['kbarticleid'];
        $result_array['subject'] = $results['subject'];
    }

    $match = $result_array['kbarticleid'];

    $queryf = "SELECT * FROM swkbarticlelinks WHERE kbarticleid = '$match'";
    $final = $search_db->query($queryf);

    while($results2 = $final->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array['linktype'] = $results2['linktype'];
    }

    echo json_encode($result_array);
}
```

There are 2 database queries as I need to run through 2 different tables.

Comment: PHP mysql extension is now deprecated, consider using **PDO_MYSQL** or **MYSQLi**.

Comment: What does var_dump($result); print?

Comment: @fardjad Where in the code he is using mysql extension ?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your line as follows

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $search_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    $query = 'SELECT kbarticleid,subject FROM swkbarticles WHERE subject LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';
    $initial = $search_db->query($query);

    while($results = $initial->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array['kbarticleid'][] = $results['kbarticleid'];
        $result_array['subject'][] = $results['subject'];
    }

    $match_detail = $result_array['kbarticleid'];

    foreach($match_detail as $match){
        $queryf = "SELECT * FROM swkbarticlelinks WHERE kbarticleid = '$match'";
        $final = $search_db->query($queryf);

        while($results2 = $final->fetch_array()) {
            $result_array['linktype'][] = $results2['linktype'];
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($result_array);
}
```

Comment: Hi Elby,I've given that a try, but no luck.

Comment: @JPDP How many result will get in this line $match = $result_array['kbarticleid'];

Comment: That line only gets 1, however it should get as many results are returned.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $search_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

$result_array = array();
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {

    $query = 'SELECT kbarticleid,subject FROM swkbarticles WHERE subject LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';
    $initial = $search_db->query($query);

    $i = 0;
    while($results = $initial->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[$i]['kbarticleid'] = $results['kbarticleid'];
        $result_array[$i]['subject'] = $results['subject'];

        $queryf = "SELECT * FROM swkbarticlelinks WHERE kbarticleid = '".$results['kbarticleid']."'";
        $final = $search_db->query($queryf);


        while($results2 = $final->fetch_array()) {
            $result_array[$i]['linktype'][] = $results2['linktype'];
        }  
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode($result_array);
}
```